# What causes this pattern in the reflection of a laser on a screen?

Tags: optics, laser, diffraction, light-emitting-diodes

When I shine a red laser behind me at a wall I see a strange reflection occurring on my laptop screen Why does this happen? The pattern on my screen occurs exactly where the laser is hitting the wall. When I shine the laser on a reflective surface(glass) I still see the same pattern on my monitor as well as the reflected laser in front of me.[image]

Comment: It's a diffraction pattern caused by the pixels in the screen.  See here:  [Diffraction Pattern on LCD Screen](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167892/)